# Extracting the last characters from a string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings:

```
c("brown::value-twostancenpq", "twitter_ld_homepage:xxxRestApisCreateTweet::create_longesttweetthereis::TaggedId",
"dumbRestApi::check_allProducts::ProductId", "dumbRestApi::check_allCustomers::CustomerId",
"twitter_ld_homepage:unknownApisCreateEdit::create_id::NewProfileId")
```

I am trying to extract the tail of the string that occurs after the last double-colons.
Because of varying lengths and multiple occurrences of double-colons, I am finding it difficult to code this in R.

| Desired Result |
| --- |
| value-twostancenpq |
| TaggedId |
| ProductId |
| CustomerId |
| NewProfileId |

Comment: Your sample data does not work

Comment: if it happens to be a column in a dataframe,  `tidyr::separate_wider_regex(dataframe, string_column, c(".*::", new_colum = ".*"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sub` with `.*::` where `.*::` matches everything until the last `::`.

```
sub(".*::", "", s)
# sub(".*:", "", s) #Alternative for this case
#[1] "value-twostancenpq" "TaggedId"           "ProductId"         
#[4] "CustomerId"         "NewProfileId"
```

Data

```
s <- c("brown::value-twostancenpq",
       "twitter_ld_homepage:xxxRestApisCreateTweet::create_longesttweetthereis::TaggedId",
       "dumbRestApi::check_allProducts::ProductId",
       "dumbRestApi::check_allCustomers::CustomerId",
       "twitter_ld_homepage:unknownApisCreateEdit::create_id::NewProfileId")
```

Answer (score 1):

data:

```
mydata <-c("brown::value-twostancenpq", "twitter_ld_homepage:xxxRestApisCreateTweet::create_longesttweetthereis::TaggedId",
"dumbRestApi::check_allProducts::ProductId", "dumbRestApi::check_allCustomers::CustomerId",
"twitter_ld_homepage:unknownApisCreateEdit::create_id::NewProfileId")
```

You can use strsplit() to split each string into substrings separated by '::'.

As a result you get a list of vectors of varying lenghts:

```
> str_split(mydata, '::')
[[1]]
[1] "brown"              "value-twostancenpq"

[[2]]
[1] "twitter_ld_homepage:xxxRestApisCreateTweet"
[2] "create_longesttweetthereis"
[3] "TaggedId"

[[3]]
[1] "dumbRestApi"       "check_allProducts" "ProductId"

[[4]]
[1] "dumbRestApi"        "check_allCustomers" "CustomerId"

[[5]]
[1] "twitter_ld_homepage:unknownApisCreateEdit"
[2] "create_id"
[3] "NewProfileId"
```

You can use sapply to get the last element of each vector.

```
> sapply(strsplit(mydata, '::'), tail, 1)
[1] "value-twostancenpq" "TaggedId"           "ProductId"
[4] "CustomerId"         "NewProfileId"
```